# Adding timestamp and user to bash history

Tags: bash, history

I want to add the timestamp and user, who executed the command to my history command. Is this even possible?

By adding this line to the ~/.bashrc, you're able to add the timestamps to the history command:

```
    HISTTIMEFORMAT="[ %Y/%m/%d %T ] "
```

This results in something like this by running *history*:

```
     1841  [ 2016/08/25 10:57:54 ] ls
     1842  [ 2016/08/25 10:57:56 ] who
     1843  [ 2016/08/25 10:57:59 ] last
     1844  [ 2016/08/25 10:58:10 ] uptime
     1845  [ 2016/08/25 10:58:13 ] history
```

Now, I want an additional info: Which real user has executed these commands?

Yes, the history is saved and written for each individual user to the $HISTFILE (~/.bash_history), but usually has every user his own login like "firstname-name" or anything else.

An example user called "max-mustermann" logs in via SSH and switches to the user "root" for example. The user "max-mustermann" is now acting as "root".

I want to log the "real" user (in this case "max-mustermann") and maybe some additional information like the used IP address, to be able to identify, who has executed the command "uptime" as user "root". I thought, I've found a solution, but it didn't really work. Add the following lines to your ~/.bashrc to test it:

```
    TTY_CON=$(tty | cut -d '/' -f 3-);
    HIST_WHO_INFO=$(who | grep "${TTY_CON}" | cut -d ' ' -f 1,12);
    HISTTIMEFORMAT="[ %Y/%m/%d %T by ${HIST_WHO_INFO} ] "
```

This returns something like this:

```
     1848  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:47 by max-mustermann (10.50.1.42:S.0) ] ls
     1849  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:48 by max-mustermann (10.50.1.42:S.0) ] who
     1850  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:49 by max-mustermann (10.50.1.42:S.0) ] last
     1851  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:51 by max-mustermann (10.50.1.42:S.0) ] uptime
     1852  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:52 by max-mustermann (10.50.1.42:S.0) ] history
```

That's perfect, but unfortunately, it doesn't keep / save the real user with the history. If somebody else logs in, all commands, which were executed as user "max-mustermann" in this example would get updated to the new user, who has logged in:

```
     1848  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:47 by somebody-else (10.50.1.18) ] ls
     1849  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:48 by somebody-else (10.50.1.18) ] who
     1850  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:49 by somebody-else (10.50.1.18) ] last
     1851  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:51 by somebody-else (10.50.1.18) ] uptime
     1852  [ 2016/08/25 11:06:52 by somebody-else (10.50.1.18) ] history
     1853  [ 2016/08/25 11:08:13 by somebody-else (10.50.1.18) ] history
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not always possible, depending on your server configuration and user behaviour, but can be if you "educate" your users properly. There are 2 ways (that I know of) you can get this information.

1. Just let your users only use `sudo` whenever they actually need it. Don't "switch" to root and start running commands. Just run seperate commands with a sudo prefix whenever you actually need root access. That way the history is still saved per user (and a sudo log will be written to the /var/log/auth.log file on most systems).
2. Make them switch to root using `sudo su` and *not* `sudo su -`, the `-` will reset their environment variables. But if you omit that `-`, the root enviroment variables should have a `SUDO_USER` variable holding the user that switched to the account. For example:

   ```
   oldskool@server:~$ sudo su
   root@server:/home/oldskool# echo $SUDO_USER
   oldskool
   ```

You could use that `SUDO_USER` in your history timeformat.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but unfortunately, it's the same result with your second tip. Instead of "sudo su" you could also use "sudo -i", but there happens the same. The first solution is no option for me, but might be a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

`HISTTIMEFORMAT` will only save epoch to `HISTFILE`. You can't add any other text. Instead, I create different files per user:

```
echo "export HISTSIZE=10000" >> ~/.bash_profile

echo "export HISTTIMEFORMAT=\"%F %T \"" >> ~/.bash_profile

echo "export HISTFILE=\"/root/.bash_history_\$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')\"" >> ~/.bash_profile

echo "export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```